# Windows : Extract names and last update times for files located in sub-folders

Tags: windows, files

I am working on a project for which I need to extract the location / name / last update time for files located in a subfloders (on windows)

Ex case : Folder 1 - File 1.A, File 1.B / Folder 2 - File 2.A

Ex results :
--> Folder 1 | File 1.A | 12/12/2009
--> Folder 1 | File 1.B | 01/01/2009
--> Folder 2 | File 2.A | 12/12/2009

I have already found commands to get the names and locations of the files in subfolders : dir /s /b | sort >agenda.txt

How can I get last update time ?

Thks

Comment: adding /T:W  in dir command should do the trick

Comment: i tried dir /T:W /s /b | sort >agenda.txt and dir /s /b/T:W | sort >agenda.txt but it did not work

Comment: I don't suppose you can use PowerShell?  It'd be much easier: `Get-ChildItem -Path "<your path>" -File -Recurse | Select-Object -Property FullName,LastWriteTime` or `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Select-Object -Property Name,Directory,LastWriteTime`

Comment: Thanks, it works but I have 2 issues : 1. All the files of my computer are listed whereas I only want the the files in "folder A" and its subfolders / 2. I do not know how to extract the results into an Excel file

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is the way to go

`get-childitem -Recurse | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Select Name, LastWriteTime, directory`

Comment: Thanks, it works pretty well but I have 2 issues : 1. All the files of my computer are listed whereas I only want the the files in "folder A" and its subfolders / 2. I do not know how to extract the results into an Excel file

Comment: @Mrick298 get-childitem works just like the `dir` command. Either start it in the directory you want to start from or use the `-path` option. If you want comma separated results look into the `export-csv` command in powershell